# Is there a word or phrase that describes something created for sharing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes something that was created specifically to be shared (as opposed to kept by the creator, or sold). But not necessarily given away, like a gift, but potentially owned by the creator and shared or given to someone else to be shared.

Likewise is there a word that describes the act of creating in this context.

Comment: If you share something, by definition you relinquish ownership to some degree. Otherwise you're hiring out (for a return).

Comment: I've posted an answer, but you might get a better answer if you go into more detail: there are many kinds of sharing and many things that can be shared.

Comment: From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: If something is created to be widely shared, you could call it *communal* — ["participated in, shared, or used in common by members of a group or community"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/communal)

Answer (score 1):

**Sharable** or **shareable** mean capable of being shared ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sharable)). It's often used of foodstuffs designed to be shared, e.g. [Trendhunter](https://www.trendhunter.com/slideshow/sharable-meals), [Mission Foods](https://www.missionfoods.com/recipes/collections/shareable-appetizers/).

Alternatives like **sharing** (as a modifier) are also used ([BBC Goodfood](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/sharing-recipes) talks about "sharing recipes"). ([tear-and-share](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/tear-share-recipes) or pull-apart bread are more specific alternatives for recipes where you can tear off a piece and take it with you.)

There are various other forms with the word "share", such as **shareware** software ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shareware): "a type of proprietary software which is initially shared by the owner for trial use at little or no cost with usually limited functionality or incomplete documentation but which can be upgraded upon payment"), but this doesn't seem to match exactly what you're talking about as it's really a marketing ploy. So you have a wide range of formations from "share" to choose from.

Comment: Shareware is a really good example, I suppose I’m looking for that but with material goods.